# Abstract class and abastract Unitest

Tags: python, django, testing

I use Django Rest Framework and I wrote something like this:

```py
class Vehicule(ABC):
    wheel = None
    roof = None

    def drive():
        use wheel and roof, blabla...

class Car(Vehicule):
    wheel = 4
    roof = True

class Bike(Vehicule):
    wheel = 2
    roof = False
```

It's working good and I want to write unitest with it.I want to write someting similar:

```py
class TestVehicule(ABC, TestCase):
    wheel = None
    roof = None
    factory = None
    
    def test_how_many_wheel(self):
        self.assertEqual(factory.wheel, self.wheel)

    def test_is_roof(self):
        self.assertEqual(factory.roof, self.roof)

class TestCar(TestVehicule)
    wheel = 4
    roof = True
    factory = CarFactory

class TestBike(TestVehicule)
    wheel = 2
    roof = False
    factory = BikeFactory
```

The goal is to write tests in TestVehicule and inherit in others class change variable and do all the tests with the child variable

Comment: Two problems: 1) `TestVehicle` should inherit from `unittest.TestCase` 2) `TestCar` and `TestBike` should probably inherit from `TestVehicle`.

Comment: Yes miswrite, I correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way around the problem would be to only inherit `TestCase` for your non-abstract classes:

```py
class TestVehicle(ABC):
    ...

class TestCar(TestVehicle, unittest.TestCase):
    ...

class TestBike(TestVehiule, unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

Technically, your `TestVehicle` doesn't even need to be abstract at this point, if all you want is for `unittest` to ignore its cases.